# How to make my themes compatible with different WordPress versions?

Tags: theme-development

I can make my themes compatible with different browsers by tweaking CSS a little bit. But I am wondering that how can Iake my theme compatible with different WordPress versions as shown in picture. Please start from basic as I am newbie to WordPress theme designing.[image: I know browser compatibility but lack WordPress compatibility knowledge]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the core functions you are using in the theme. Let's say that you are using [`get_theme_file_uri`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/09/09/new-functions-hooks-and-behaviour-for-theme-developers-in-wordpress-4-7/) which is introduced in **WP 4.7**(not released yet) instead of it's counter parts `get_theme_directory_uri`. Your theme doesn't support older versions if you don't have any back compat functions.

Similarly every newer version of WordPress comes with new functions,API's,classes,actions,filters. So if you are using newer functions the theme doesn't support older versions of WP.